# Select a polymorphic foreign key by type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a simple polymorphic association in the mold of http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

```
class Picture < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end

class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
end
```

What I want is to grab all pictures where the `imageable_type` is a `Product`, as an example.

`Picture.imageable.where(imageable_type: "Product")` works but this doesn't seem ideal. It requires knowing the value in the type column. Is there an activerecord way of specifiying the model directly? E.g. something like this:

`Picture.imageable.where(imageable: Product)` (where Product is the activerecord model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to use `Product` instead of `"Product"` so that you can catch code problems or typos, then you can just simply do the following

```
Picture.where(imageable_type: Product.to_s)
# will run fine

Picture.where(imageable_type: Produkt.to_s)
# will raise an error as it is a typo
```

*By the way, I don't think I get what you said*

> It requires knowing the value in the type column

*because your desired `.where(imageable: Product)` still needs the value to be supplied*

### Trivia

```
Picture.where(imageable: Product)
```

...is already implemented, but you are not supposed to use it like that, but the following instead:

```
product1 = Product.first
product1_pictures = Picture.where(imageable: product1)
```

Or

```
employee1 = Employee.first
employee1_pictures = Picture.where(imageable: employee1)
```

Comment: Thanks, the issue is that the data flow for the polymorphic type is backwards unfortunately.